# Bluetooth headset microphone is not detecting on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone

I'm trying to connect my bluetooth headset on my laptop, when I pair the device audio works very well (in Settings ->Sound -> Output) I can see the headset as my output device.
but it doesn't show any input microphone, it shows only built in microphone.

My headset has wired connection too, if I connect via wire I can see both input and output preferences. But it's not taking headset mic

How to enable input headset microphone for handfree calls?

Output:

[image: output]

Input:

[image: input]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the sound profile from High Fidelity Playback A2DP Sink to HFP/HSP for the microphone to appear in settings

Comment: I did that but still i can't see headset option in input. 
Actually in wired connection also its taking inbuilt microphone not headset one. If i preffer headset the person on the other side can't hear. 
I tested same headset in android phone and Mac there it works really well

Comment: I don't know what the issue is as I just tested on my Sony headset and I was able to use the headset microphone after switching it to HSP/HFP

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have the same!